# Auth::attempt laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on project now that I have 3 sections, each section have 2 role (admin & user) and i would like to have only one login page
so I have made it but wondering if it is good or bad way

Route :

```
Route::get('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
                ->middleware('guest')
                ->name('login');

Route::post('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware('guest')->name('login.user');
```

Controller:

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);
        //section1 admin
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'is_admin' => 1,'section_id'=>1])) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard/section1/admin');
            //section1 user
        }elseif(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'is_admin' => 0,'section_id'=>1])) {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard/section1/user');

        }//section2 admin
        elseif(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'is_admin' => 1,'section_id'=>2])) {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard/section2/admin');

        }//section2 user
        elseif(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'is_admin' => 0,'section_id'=>2])) {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard/section2/user');
        }//section3 Admin
        elseif(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'is_admin' => 1,'section_id'=>3])) {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard/section3/admin');

        }//section3 user
        elseif(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'is_admin' => 0,'section_id'=>3])) {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard/section3/user');     
        }
        else{
            return back()->withErrors([
                'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
            ]);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: i wouldn't structure it this way, but with what you have i would only do 1 call to `attempt` since they are all 'users' (this is not multi-auth; just role based) ... if `attempt` returns true then you can check if they are 'admin' and then what 'section' they are assigned ... this could be like 3 lines instead of all of that

Comment: Thanks for your reply , can you show me an example . I really want to make it shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are all the same type (Model/table) you can do 1 call to `attempt` to attempt to authenticate them. Then when you have the user you can decided where to send them to dynamically. This assumes `section_id` would only ever be one of those values that matches the route URI for the sections:

```
...

if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    $user = Auth::user();

    return redirect()->intendend(
        'dashboard/section'. $user->section_id .'/'. $user->is_admin ? 'admin' : 'user'
    );
}

return back()->withErrors([
    'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
]);
```

Also, understand the way `intended` works, if the user was redirected to the login page from some where else that is where they would be redirected to not the 'path' you are defining there unless there wasn't an 'intended' location set in the session (due to the redirect to the login page from the 'auth' middleware for example).

Comment: Thank you so much . I like how you organise the code , I learnt a lot from you .. thank you so much